# Как убрать пагинацию в битрикс в определенных разделах, если не имееются товары?

Tags: php, битрикс

[image]

В конце урла имеется PAGEN... как от него избавиться?

Comment: Откуда появляется  PAGEN? Если после перехода по кнопкам погинацыи то всё нормально. А если пагинация есть а товаров нет (по всем страницам пагинации) то возможно неактивные какие нибудь товары прокидываются в пагинацию. Проблема не ясна. Либо вы просто хотите редирект сделать что бы без  PAGEN был?

Comment: Вот при скрытом разделе пагинация все равно остается http://electrocabel24.ru/catalog/kabelnaya_produkciya_kupit_kabel/provod_i_kabel_optom/?PAGEN_5=9

Comment: Типа нужно что бы если 2 товара или меньше в подразделе ее вообще не было

Comment: http://electrocabel24.ru/catalog/kabelnaya_produkciya_kupit_kabel/provod_i_kabel_optom/?PAGEN_5=asd - и так тоже, пользователь может любое написать в урл, всё не убрать. Какая у вас проблема непонятно, где то есть пагинация в которой ссылки неправельные? Может вы хотите 404 отдавать если раздела нет?